# Twilio SMS Response

Tags: asp.net, twilio

Looking at using the twilio api to receive text messages
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey

its says create a page and add the following code

```
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Hello, Mobile Monkey</Message>
</Response>
```

So I created this page "sms-hello-monkey.aspx" updated the pointer and no response, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Couple of things to check:

1. Can you load the page in a browser from a publicly accessible URL?
2. In your account dashboard did you update the Message URL for your [Twilio phone number](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming) to be that public URL?

[image]

3. Are there any errors being reporting in your [App Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor)?

Hope that helps.